# Averaging weights learned during backpropogation

Tags: neural-networks

Is it possible to train a neural network N times, using backpropogation and then average the weights learned to produce a more accurate classifier?

My tests are indicating no, but I'm unsure if it is an implementation error?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Averaging the weights of different networks won't work. It is not an implementation error.

One possibility is to train several networks using [bootstrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) on the training data, and then average the prediction (or using some voting mechanism if you do classification) of the whole ensemble of networks. This is called [bagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating). Bagging makes most sense when your classifier has a strong tendency to overfit.

A very recent approach which is reported to work very well in terms of performance and computation is [dropout](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0580v1.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up.

Could you explain why this isn't possible ? It seems intuitively like it should work ?

Comment: Let us assume you are doing classification. You can think of neurons as feature detectors, were the output represents the conditional probability of having that feature. When averaging the weights of different networks, you combine weights that might represent detectors for different features.

Comment: An ANN can have many equivalent minima of the error function that have totally different weights. Averaging can result in a weight vector that is not even in a local minimum.

Comment: As a further pointer to dropout, see section 2 of the maxout paper, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.4389v3.pdf